# CSRF Token request security

Tags: php, security, drupal, drupal-7, csrf

A Drupal website that my company is maintaining has a REST endpoint, using Drupal Services (likely not that relevant). One of the systems that I'm writing has to write changes in the system to that website over REST. To do this, we first have to 'login' to the system, for which we get a session token and id, and then have to get a CSRF token from this same website. To get this token, we have to make a request to the website, giving the token and id we got earlier. After this, we can use the token and id, combined with the CSRF token, to make edit requests.

But why does having to request this CSRF token first make this system any more secure?

Comment: It stops duplication

Comment: By making sure only one token can be used at a time? That still wouldn't make sense to me, as it seems you also have to send along a login session cookie, which can be used to request a new token at any time.

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd use of a CSRF token, they are mainly used to stop a 3rd party site submitting form data to a sites form endpoint. As the token is issued as it renders the form. Then, when users POSTs, it will check if token is correct. It does this via a cookie.

But in your case it must be used to authenticate the REST calls, because the login id must remain the same over different sessions therefore someone sniffing this could fake calls with that id. So the token is used instead of passing the login password each time (which would be a bad idea).

Comment: But wouldn't that only make sense as a way of preventing sniffing attacks if you would not have to send your login cookie along every time you try to put or post data? That same cookie can be used to request a new CSRF token either way.

Comment: cookies are domain specific so a 3rd party site trying to post to your endpoint wouldn't be able to read the cookie, and therefore get a token or use a token. The CS of CSRF is all about "Cross Site" so to stop another site posting data.

Answer (score 0):

If the REST API is used by web clients also, the CSRF token will be required to protect it against [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

As noted, this makes it cumbersome to be used in a server side fashion. They could introduce a flag on their back end to indicate whether an account is using the API server-side or client-side, and only require the token for client-side usage.